Why do we use OTM options to extract implied vol?
It is often common practice to calculate implied volatility using puts for low strikes and calls for high strikes, so to always employ out-of-the-money options. Why is this often preferred to using the average between put and calls implied vols for the same strike and expiration?

ITM options have wide spreads, calculating fair price for instruments with wide spreads is slightly difficult. OTMs on the other hand have tight spreads and are more liquid than ITS

You should also not use the average of put and calls because you should not build your surface from American prices directly. See here. Otherwise use the option itself.

From a purely numerical point of view, it is easier to use OTM options since their value is lower and does not include a huge deterministic component (S-K) which kills the numerical precision of doubles. They have the same amount of information as an OTM option, but given the nature of double, a lot of it is lost. For the same reason, when calibrating a model, one uses OTM options.
